# Find maximum pixel using BLOCKPROC in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, block

In **Matlab** I've got a 3D matrix (over 100 frames 512x512). My goal is to find some representative points through the whole hyper-matrix. To do so I've implemented the traditional (and not very efficient) method: I subdivide the large matrix into smaller sub-matrices and then I look for the pixel with the highest value. After doing that I change those relative coordinates of that very pixel in the sub-matrix to global coordinates referenced to the large matrix.

Now, I'm redesigning the algorithm. I've seen that in order to analyze a large matrix block-by-block (that's actually what I'm doing with my old algorithm) the **BLOCKPROC** function is very efficient. I've read the documentation but I don't know how the "fun" function should be implemented to extract that the pixel with the highest value of each block. Thank you in advance.

*I'm trying to get the coordinates of those maximum pixels referenced to the global matrix, I really don't care about their value.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. Why don't you use max() function for every frame? And then use find() and ind2sub(). Like in this thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170759

Comment: because in each frame there are several of those points I'm looking for. It's too long to explain... Briefly: I've got images (a 3D stack) from a microscope in which there are many fibres (collagen fibres). I've to find some points (several pixels in each frame) and, after doing so interpolate the points and reconstruct the fibres. Those points are called Nucleation Points, the best way to find them is to do what I've explained in the question.

Comment: I think is pretty simple what I'm trying to do. Subdivide the image into smaller images and get the coordinates (referenced to the global image) of the maximum pixel of each of those smaller images.

Comment: If you know the value you want to find, find() function would return indices of ALL points you are looking for. You can even use logical expression. Or maybe I misunderstand what you mean by 'max' value. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: That is true. However several pixels in the same sub-matrix can have the same value.

Comment: So you want them all? Its indexes?

Comment: Yes. The index of the pixel with the highest value inside each sub-matrix.(in the case the are >1 with that maximum value, it will be fine to take just one). Hesar, I've already done this. I'm trying to do it in a more efficient way and I think that using "blockproc" is the best way but I don't know how.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45898/discussion-between-hesar-and-karl71)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define a function to find the location of the maximum of a (sub)matrix:

```
function loc = max_location(M);
[~, ii] = max(M(:));
[r c] = ind2sub(size(M),ii);
loc = [r c];
```

Then use

```
blockproc(im, blocksize, @(x) x.location+max_location(x.data)-1)
```

where `im` is your image (2D array) and `blocksize` is a 1x2 vector specifying block size. Within `blockproc`, the `data` field is the submatrix (which you pass to `max_location`), and the `location` field contains the coordinates of the top-left corner of the submatrix (which you add to the result of `max_location`, minus 1).

Example:

```
>> blocksize = [3 3];

>> im = [ 0.3724    0.0527    0.4177        0.6981    0.0326    0.4607
          0.1981    0.7379    0.9831        0.6665    0.5612    0.9816
          0.4897    0.2691    0.3015        0.1781    0.8819    0.1564

          0.3395    0.4228    0.7011        0.1280    0.6692    0.8555
          0.9516    0.5479    0.6663        0.9991    0.1904    0.6448
          0.9203    0.9427    0.5391        0.1711    0.3689    0.3763 ];

>> blockproc(im, blocksize, @(x) x.location+max_location(x.data)-1)

ans =
     2     3     2     6
     5     1     5     4
```

meaning your block maxima are located at coordinates (2,3), (5,1), (2,6) and (5,4)

Comment: How can I apply this algorithm to a multidimensional matrix (x,y,z), not just a single frame? (I would like to have a block size [3 3 3])

Comment: `blockproc` is only for 2D as far as I know. You could perhaps reshape the 3D array into a 2D array and then you could apply `blockproc`

Comment: This is a solution (implement blockproc with 3D array) implemented by Dr. Ramón Casero(University of Oxford): http://code.google.com/p/gerardus/source/browse/trunk/matlab/FiltersToolbox/blockproc3.m

Answer (score 1):

Another possiblity is to use `im2col` for each frame.  If `I` is your frame (512,512):

```
% rearranges 512 x 512 image into 4096 x 64
% each column of I2 represents a 64 x 64 block 
n = 64;
I2 = im2col(I,[n,n],'distinct'); 

% find max in each block
% ~ to ignore that output
[~,y] = max(I2);

% convert those values to overall indices
ind = sub2ind(size(I2),y, 1:n);

% create new matrix
I3 = zeros(size(I2));
I3(ind)=1;
I3 = col2im(I3,[n,n],size(I),'distinct');
```

`I3` should now be an image the same size of input `I` but with all zeros except for the locations of the maximum points in each sub-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

the tricky part with the function handle "fun" is that it refers to the subblocks which are a struct, this is an object with one or more fields and one or more values assigend to each of the fields.

The values of your subblocks are stored in a field called "data" so the function call

```
@(x)max(x)
```

is not enough, in this case the correct version of that is

```
@(x)max(x.data)
```

A 2D example of what you are looking for would look like this:

```
a=magic(4);

b=blockproc(a,[2,2],@(x) find(x.data==max(max(x.data)))); %linear indexes
```

outputs

```
a =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1


b =

     1     3
     4     2
```

`b` are the linear indexes of each subblock, so that's the values 16, 13, 14, 15 in `a`.

Hope that helps!