# Transform relative cell coordinates to absolute matrix coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, coordinate-systems

In **Matlab** I've got a big matrix (512x512x100). In order to analyze it I have used blockproc. Due to the fact that blockproc only accepts 2D matrices I have transformed my original matrix into a 2D matrix using **mat2cell** and some other consequent steps. The blockproc function search for the pixel with the highest value in each sub-matrix and returns its coordinates referenced to that very sub-matrix.

After a couple of steps I've got the coordinates of those maximum pixels referenced to the first **mat2cell** transformation. Now I would like to convert those coordinates to global coordinates, that is, absolute coordinates in the large original 3D matrix.

I've try some things with this example:

d=rand(4,4,4)

d(:,:,1) =

```
0.0451    0.8044    0.0784    0.7859
0.8911    0.3481    0.4636    0.9806
0.4887    0.5677    0.0999    0.9488
0.7822    0.0467    0.5569    0.2256
```

d(:,:,2) =

```
0.8131    0.8880    0.8066    0.8103
0.8240    0.3358    0.8422    0.2552
0.8364    0.2759    0.3753    0.7741
0.9853    0.8297    0.3745    0.5936
```

d(:,:,3) =

```
0.1200    0.1841    0.3897    0.0894
0.0747    0.7485    0.4866    0.4722
0.8387    0.9523    0.0166    0.5013
0.8210    0.3107    0.6935    0.1286
```

d(:,:,4) =

```
0.6424    0.7322    0.4631    0.1684
0.5523    0.0953    0.0168    0.6231
0.1073    0.5530    0.8504    0.9304
0.3482    0.7804    0.7657    0.2496
```

After doing the **mat2cell** I've got:

cell(:,:,1) =

```
[2x2x2 double]    [2x2x2 double]
[2x2x2 double]    [2x2x2 double]
```

cell(:,:,2) =

```
[2x2x2 double]    [2x2x2 double]
[2x2x2 double]    [2x2x2 double]
```

These are the resulting coordinates. Each row of the matrix from below represents the coordinates of the maximum pixel in each "sub-cell":

max_px =

```
 2     1
 2     3
 2     2
 1     2
 2     2
 1     2
 2     4
 1     4
```

by doing "cell{1}(2,1)" you get:

ans =

```
0.8911
```

wich is the value of the maximum pixel in the first 3D sub-batrix (first "sub-cell")

I guess the is a pretty straight forward way to convert those relative coordinates to global, but I don't know how. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I already answered that in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21305443/2586922). Use the `.location` field of the block as in my answer

Comment: Thank you again, Luis. I've used what you told me in my previos question. The result is the coordinate matrix of the example from above. My new problem is how to transform those local coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to use blockproc. I don't know why anyone ever does...

```
  dcell=mat2cell(d,...);

  mask=cell2mat(  cellfun(@(c) eq(c,max(c(:))) , dcell, 'uni',0) ) ;

  [imax,jmax,kmax]=ind2sub(size(d), find(mask(:)));
```

This assumes that there is a unique max in each sub-array, which you also appear to have assumed.

Comment: I'm not looking for the max value in each sub-array, but for its coordinates referenced to the global matrix.

Comment: That's what I gave you.

Comment: Ok. The second line is not running. The last line (third) will get the coordinates. You are right!

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure you didn't miss any of my Edits.

Comment: I love you, man! Thank you so much! But... any idea of how to solve my problem from the question? (using the coordinates that already have)

Comment: Matt, if I want not to take the maximum value but the maximum value only if it's over a threshold value, How should i write it? I'm lost with handle functions, cell fun... Thank you

Comment: I think you mean this eq(c,max( [c(:);threshold] )). Otherwise, what result should be returned if the max is less than the threshold?

Comment: If the max is below the threshold, it should be skipped and analyze the next sub-matrix

Answer (score 0):

This uses the max_px that you already have. The 4th and 5th line just convert max_px to more natural 3D coordinates, so maybe those could be omitted, and the code shortened, if you can get it in that form to begin with.

```
dcell=mat2cell(d,...);   


[outer_dims{1:3}]=size(dcell); outer_dims=[outer_dims{:}],
[inner_dims{1:3}]=size(dcell{1}); inner_dims=[inner_dims{:}],

idx=sub2ind(inner_dims,max_px(:,1),max_px(:,2));

[ii,jj,kk]= ind2sub(inner_dims,idx); %get 3-inner max coodinates


[X,Y,Z]=ndgrid(1:outer_dims(1),1:outer_dims(2), 1:outer_dims(3));

dims6=[inner_dims; outer_dims];

idx6=sub2ind(dims6(:).', ii,X(:),jj,Y(:),kk,Z(:));

 [imax,jmax,kmax]  = ind2sub(size(d),idx6);
```